# What is meant by Adhi-Vyadhi?

Tags: terminology, meaning

I heard the word **Adhi-Vyadhi** (ఆధివ్యాధులు) several times in preachings as well as in scriptural books.

Example: [From Sloka 3](https://dhwarakamai.org/kaakad.html)

What is the exact meaning for that word?

Comment: If you can give an example of where you found it in scriptures it will make things clear.

Comment: okay. @Rickross

Comment: Which language is that?

Comment: @Rickross I think Hindi. In Telugu also, the word is used.

Comment: Adi can mean "etc." and also "the first, beginning". Not sure how does it fit in with Vyadhi. Vyadhi however means disease. See for example the last stanza of the Phala Sruti [here](http://www.hindupedia.com/en/Surya_ashtakam)

Comment: The correct words are Adhi-Vyadhi , generally a third word called upadhi is also used with these two. Adhi - आधी- Mental , Vyadhi -व्याधि - Physical & Upadhi -उपाधि - emotional.
These three words are often usedin stotras to convey that it can cure these 3 types of pain or sufferings. So the meaning of Adhi and Vyadhi has to be understood in this way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means "sorrow and disease".

From [Apte dictionary](https://www.sanskritdictionary.com/%C4%81dhi%E1%B8%A5/6696/4):

> ādhiḥ आधिः
>
> Definition: **आधिः** m. [आधीयते स्थाप्यते प्रतीकाराय मनो$नेन, आ-धा-कि
> P.III.3.92; connected with आध्यै in some senses] 1 **Mental pain or
> anguish, agony, anxiety** (opp. **व्याधि- which is bodily pain**);

Here's an example from [Mahābhārata](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/mbs/mbs01058.htm):

> Book 1
>
> Chapter 58
>
> 10 tato 'vardhanta dharmeṇa sahasraśatajīvinaḥ 
>      tāḥ prajāḥ pṛthivīpāla dharmavrataparāyaṇāḥ 
>      **ādhibhir** **vyādhibhiś** caiva vimuktāḥ sarvaśo narāḥ

K M Ganguli's [translation](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01065.htm):

> And, O protector of the earth, hundreds of thousands of creatures were born, and all were virtuous and began to multiply in virtue, all being **free from sorrow and disease**.

[Another example](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/mbs/mbs13018.htm):

> Book 13
>
> Chapter 18
>
> 33 [māṇḍavya] 
>      acauraś caura śaṅkāyāṃ śūle bhinno hy ahaṃ yadā 
>      tatrasthena stuto devaḥ prāha māṃ vai maheśvaraḥ
>
> 34 mokṣaṃ prāpsyasi śullāc ca jīviṣyasi samārbudam 
>      rujā śūlakṛtā caiva na te vipra bhaviṣyati 
>      **ādhibhir vyādhibhiś** caiva varjitas tvaṃ bhaviṣyasi
>
> [Mandavya said](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m13/m13a018.htm),--'In former times though not a thief and yet wrongly suspected of theft, I was impaled (under the orders of a king). I then adored the illustrious Mahadeva who said unto me,--Thou shalt soon be freed from impalement and live for millions of years. The pangs due to impalement shall not be thine. **Thou shalt also be freed from every kind of affliction and disease.**

Answer (score 2):

VyAdhi means disease, ailment etc.

See a [dictionary](https://spokensanskrit.org/index.php?tran_input=vyAdhI&direct=se&script=hk&link=yes&mode=3):

> व्याधि        m.  vyAdhi      illness 
>      व्याधि     m.  vyAdhi      ailment     
> व्याधित       adj.    vyAdhita        sick    
>      व्याधीयमान     adj.
> vyAdhIyamAna        ailing  
>      व्याधी     f.  vyAdhI      care    
>      व्याधी     f.
> vyAdhI      sorrow  
>      व्याधि     m.  vyAdhi      plague  
>      व्याधि     m.
> vyAdhi      disease

If there is Dirgha-E kara at the end then the meaning is different (sorrow, care).

From the last stanza of the Phala Sruti of the [Surya Ashtakam](http://www.hindupedia.com/en/Surya_ashtakam):

> Sthree thails madhu maamsani.,
>  Yasth yejathu raver dhine,
> **Na vyadhi** soka dharidhryam,
>  Surya lokam sa gachathi.
>
> One who forsakes on all Sundays, Woman oil bath, meat and drinks, Will
> **never be sick** nor sad nor poor. And would reach the land of sun after death.

So, regarding VyAdhi's meaning, there is no confusion.
 
But, Adi's meaning will vary depending on the spelling. Adi can mean the first, beginning etc..

Comment: What what is Aadhi there?

Comment: Is it Adhi or Adi? @hanugm

Comment: May be, if adi means the first here, then the whole thing means "the first disease". @hanugm

Comment: Sorry for changing question frequently...

Comment: @hanugm "d" and "t" are written as "dh" and "th" in South India.

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto Yeah changed now...

Comment: @hanugm But that's just the transliteration which vary. the pronunciation stays same. So it is not changing anything w.r.t. your question.